# Cannot install pygame_sdl2

Tags: python, python-install

When I run the **setup.py** file, there is an error. I have cloned the **pygame_sdl2** repository and followed the above instructions, but there is an error. I found a post with the same error as me, but I tried his solution, but there was still no solution

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\17835\Desktop\练习\pygame_sdl2\setup.py", line 60, in <module>
    parse_cflags([ "sh", "-c", "sdl2-config --cflags" ])
  File "C:\Users\17835\Desktop\练习\pygame_sdl2\setuplib.py", line 95, in parse_cflags
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, universal_newlines=True)
  File "E:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "E:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "E:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "E:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system could not find the specified file.
```

I repeated running the command 'python setup.py install' but still got the same result